# AES calculation CMAC Java to Swift

Tags: swift, authentication, aes

I am trying to calculate CMAC

```java
byte[] key={0x09,0x11,0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x13,0x14,0x36,0x58,0x7A,0x02,0x03};
AES mAES=new AES();
mAES.AesInit(key);
byte[] response = mAES.calcCMAC(challenge);
```

Swift i am using the lib CryptoSwift

```swift
let key = [0x09,0x11,0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x13,0x14,0x36,0x58,0x7A,0x02,0x03] as [UInt8]
let message:NSData = NSData.fromHexString("DA55C255")
let mac = Authenticator.Poly1305(key: key).authenticate(message.arrayOfBytes())
```

But it's not working as expected.

the expected result is

Challenge isDA55C255
Response isED7CA01A

Comment: What's not working?  What are your results?  How do they differ from your expected results?

Comment: what makes you think that Poly1305 and CMAC are the same thing? They are not.

Answer (score 0):

we don't find any solution, we have created our own classe

https://gist.github.com/bolom/b426a0163943b576175b

Comment: Why are you re-implementing AES in Swift when there is a FIPS certified version as part of Common Crypto (CCCrypt) and it is orders of magnitude faster?

Comment: The `Int8sToHex` method is broken, consider replacing it with something like: `public func Int8sToHex(var Int8s : [Int8]) -> String {` `var hexString = ""` `for  var j : Int = 0; j < Int8s.count; j++ {` `let vu =  UInt8(bitPattern: Int8(Int8s[j]))` `hexString += String(format: "%02x", vu)` ` }` `return hexString` `}`

Comment: i don't find any exemple who allow me to caculate CMAC of an AES. If you have a code that. Please show me

Comment: OK, I'll work that up. It is farly easy, it basically is modyfing the last block prior to CBC encryption with an iv of 0.

Comment: i have update my code with the new Int8sToHex. Can you update directly my code with your suggestion ?

Comment: As I said, why use untrusted AES code when Common Crypto provides a well vetted much faster implementation? Further the code suffers from using `Int8` instead of `UInt8` while the the data is an array of unsigned bytes. There are methods with terribly undescriptive names such as `__` and `_u`. A goal of code is that it should be easy to understand and names should be well considered and descriptive of their function.